# How can I slice and keep text in a list every specific character?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I used beautifulsoup and I got a result form .get_text(). The result contains a long text:

```
alpha = ['\n\n\n\nIntroduction!!\nGood\xa0morning.\n\n\n\nHow\xa0are\xa0you?\n\n']
```

It can be noticed that the number of **\n** is not the same, and there are **\xa0** for spacing.

I want to slice every group of **\n** (**\n\n** or **\n\n\n** or **\n\n\n\n** ) and replace **\xa0** with a space in a new list, to look like this:

```
beta = ['Introduction!!','Good morning.','How are you?']
```

How can I do it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a little script that solves your problem:

```py
alpha = ['\n\n\n\nIntroduction!!\nGood\xa0morning.\n\n\n\nHow\xa0are\xa0you?\n\n']
beta = []
for s in alpha:
    # Turning the \xa0 into spaces
    s = s.replace('\xa0',' ')
    # Breaking the string by \n
    s = s.split('\n')
    # Explanation 1
    s = list(filter(lambda s: s!= '',s))
    # Explanation 2
    beta = beta + s
print(beta)
```

### Explanation 1

As there is some sequences of `\n` inside the `alpha` string, the `split()` will generate some empty strings. The `filter()` that I wrote removes them from the list.

### Explanation 2

When the `s` string got split, it turns into a list of strings. Then, we need to concatenate the lists.

Comment: Interesting idea! You can even simplify it (and avoid the loop and a second list) by using `join()`; as in `alpha = "".join(alpha).replace('\xa0',' ').split('\n')
alpha = list(filter(lambda a: a != '', alpha))`.

Comment: @JackFleeting great suggestion! I did it step by step to more easy to understand. And, I just noticed now that I could just merge the lists, instead of iterating over it

Comment: Thank you very much sir, you made my day.

Comment: @james_24 you're welcome! As this seems to have solved your problem, feel free to set it as the solution!